# Fill Form by Clicking Text Link?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, onclick

I need a code like this.
This is an example but it is not working to IE7

[http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pc4uT](http://fiddle.jshell.net/McLaren/Pc4uT/)

Theese are my links :

1. Link 1
2. Link 2
3. Link 3
4. Link 4
5. Link 5

it must filling to input field with link value when click to links.
Like this : 1,2,3,4,5

Can someone help me for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.click(` instead of `attr("onclick", ...` To be compatible with different browsers and don't return a string of javascript. You should avoid putting anything that looks like scripting inside a string. Use this:

```
$("a.mylink").each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
         document.getElementById('row1').value += i + ',';
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the value in a data attribute for each link:

```
<a href="#" data-val="1" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" data-val="2" class="link">Link 2</a>
etc.
```

Then you could retrieve the value and insert it into the input:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    $('#input_id').val($('#input_id').val()+', '+$(this).data('val'));
});
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` should be `$('#input_id').val()` because `this` is the clicked link, not the input.

Answer (score 1):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pc4uT/37/ see here it works

You need to use click instead of attr

```
$("a.mylink").click(function (arr) {
    if($('#row1').val()==''){
        $('#row1').val( $(this).attr('name'));
    }else{
      $('#row1').val( $('#row1').val()+','+$(this).attr('name'));
    }
});
```

and you can use name in link to kee the link number

```
<a class="mylink" name="1">First Link</a>     
    <a class="mylink" name="2">Second Link</a>
```

Comment: Just worth to mention that "==" needs to be replaced by "===".